# Solving differentiation word problem

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

I am trying to solve the following problem from an MIT calculus practice exam.

> A hawk is pursuing a mouse. We choose a coordinate system so the
> mouse runs along the $x$-axis in the negative direction, and the hawk is flying over the $x$-axis, swooping down along the exponential curve y = $e^{kx}$, for some positive constant $k$. The hawk in flight is always aimed directly at the mouse. It is noon at the equator, and the sun is directly overhead. When the hawk’s shadow on the ground is at the point $x_0$, where is the mouse?

I haven't looked at the solution, but I can't make sense of this problem or even where to start or how this pertains to differentiation, though it surely does. I would appreciate any hints on how to get started, and I'll update this original post with an updated attempt.

Comment: You must draw a picture !

Answer (score 1):

Only hints (as you requested) to help you translate this into a calculus problem. The solution is left to you.

The hawk follows the trajectory of $y = e^{kx}$. At a given point $x_0$, what is the slope of the tangent to the curve?

That slope will tell you the direction of the line of sight of the hawk to the mouse (the hawk has its vision fixed on its prey).

The mouse is confined to the $x$-axis. Using that slope you previously worked out, and the instantaneous position of the hawk (you can find the coordinates in terms of $x_0$ - the whole "shadow at noon" thing is just to tell you that the hawk is directly above its own shadow), can you figure out the equation of the tangent line? That will be the exact line of sight of the hawk to the mouse at any given time.

Now that you have that equation, you can work out the $x$-intercept of that tangent line. That will give you the position of the mouse.

The final answer is surprisingly simple.